# How to fix vscode settings?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

JSON error:

[image]

I didn't remeber what is delete/remove something in this setting.Is this wrong format?

Comment: Please add code as code, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

setting.json must start with "{" and end with "}".
Can you try putting the first line of language-configurations.json be modified into braces as required? Don't put it in front of "{"